# Spyder not accepting keyboard interaction

Tags: python, pip, keyboard, conda, spyder

When trying to uninstall a pip package in Spyder 3.3.6 using
`pip uninstall tensorflowjs`
I get a prompt saying:
`Proceed (y/n)?`
but no leyboard interaction is accepted.
I also got this when trying to install another package using `conda create -n tfjs python=3.6.8` getting a similar prompt: `Proceed ([y]/n)?`but nothing accepted other than aborting using `^C`.

Otherwise keyboard interaction works in Spyder so I really don't get what I'm supposed to do to make pip and conda accept my keyboard inputs in the Spyder console. I found nothing in the Spyder precerences that seems to be related.

Comment: When you say "Spyder Console" do you mean the Ipython console inside Spyder? You should not issue anaconda statements inside an ipython console but rather in a bash/CLI such as e.g. Conda prompt.

Comment: Yes I mean the Ipython console in Spyder. Still, shouldn't the pip command work inside Ipython? I've installed numerous libraries without problems, like tensorflow, numpy and others that way. So I was surprised to find it got stuck on uninstall.

Comment: Inside Ipython it does indeed work. So I would probably raise that as a bug in Spyder to the developers.

Comment: Yes, I tried outide Spyder and it works for me too so a bug. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [pre-answer "yes"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/#cmdoption-y) on all questions:

```
pip uninstall -y tensorflowjs
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you. Do you know what's causing the Ipython console to lose contact with keyboard?

Comment: @Oortone No idea, sorry.